# Created VIEW to replace nested SELECT, not working

Tags: sql-server, view

SQL Server 2012

Here is a nested `SELECT` statement that works

```
SELECT DISTINCT Computer_Name, IP_Address, COUNT(Computer_ID) AS Num_Computer_ID
FROM dbo.Computers
WHERE Computer_Name in (SELECT DISTINCT Computer_Name
                        FROM dbo.Computers
                        WHERE dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
                        AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
                        GROUP BY Computer_Name,IP_Address
                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Computer_ID) > 1)
AND dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
GROUP BY Computer_Name, IP_Address
ORDER BY Num_Computer_ID DESC
```

I created a VIEW to avoid nested `SELECT` statement

```
CREATE VIEW V_Duplicate_ID 
AS SELECT DISTINCT Computer_Name
FROM dbo.Computers
WHERE dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
GROUP BY Computer_Name,IP_Address
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Computer_ID) > 1;
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM V_Duplicate_ID` it works, but when I incorporate the view to replace the nested `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT Computer_Name, IP_Address, COUNT(Computer_ID) AS Num_Computer_ID
FROM dbo.Computers, [V_Duplicate_ID]
WHERE dbo.Computers.Computer_Name = [dbo].[V_Duplicate_ID].Computer_Name
AND dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'
AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'
GROUP BY Computer_Name, IP_Address
ORDER BY Num_Computer_ID DESC
```

I get errors

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'Computer_Name'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'Computer_Name'.
```

How to fix?

Comment: add the alias of the table for the `Computer_Name` column (either `dbo.Computers` or `[V_Duplicate_ID]`). And please, don't use non ansi, deprecated implicit joins

Comment: Also, your query seems very convoluted and it can most likely be improved. Is `Computer_ID` the primary key of your `dbo.Computers` table?

Comment: @Lamak implicit joins are neither non ansi nor deprecated. They are ANSI-89 and the more common usage is ANSI-92. They are not deprecated either. They are however awful to deal with and much more prone to accidental cross join.

Comment: @SeanLange You can check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122(v=vs.100).aspx) and see the examples for "Deprecated syntax for an inner join"

Comment: @Lamak I have never seen this anywhere in SQL Server documentation. The documentation there is also incorrect, they reference that type of join as an inner join. It is a cross join which behaves like an inner join by the where clause. I am by no means suggesting it should be used because it is dreadful. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, and that "cross join which behaves like an inner join by the where clause" **is** the old way of doing an inner join, I don't understand what you mean there

Comment: @Lamak I am saying that I have never seen and sql server documentation that states it is deprecated. The link you posted is from Visual Studio documentation.

Comment: @SeanLange Alright, fair enough, the deprecated syntax for joins is for outer joins, not inner joins

Comment: @Lamak LOL that wasn't what I was saying. I am curious if the deprecated join type is actually official. The only time I have ever seen it is from the link you posted which is not sql server documentation. I would be thrilled if it is.

Comment: @SeanLange Nope, it's not deprecated syntax for inner joins, at least, not officialy. As you said, it seems that the comment in the link I posted was taking some "liberties" (and so did I) when saying "deprecated"

Comment: @Lamak well darn I was really hoping it is deprecated. Bah!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following select query, simple put **dbo.Computers** infront of Computer_Name in SELECT and GROUP BY keywords.

Because when the view is created it also have a column name Computer_name. So there is a conflict. But when u executed before the query alone, the column name would have been *DISTINCT(Computer_Name)*

```
SELECT DISTINCT **dbo.Computers.Computer_Name**,  
IP_Address, COUNT(Computer_ID) AS Num_Computer_ID  
FROM dbo.Computers, [V_Duplicate_ID]  
WHERE dbo.Computers.Computer_Name = [dbo].[V_Duplicate_ID].Computer_Name  
AND dbo.Computers.COMPUTER_NAME LIKE '%s001'  
AND dbo.Computers.IP_Address LIKE '%.100'  
GROUP BY **dbo.Computers.Computer_Name**, IP_Address  
ORDER BY Num_Computer_ID DESC
```